# Find multiples files using find command but except perticular2 file in unix command

Tags: unix

The below command will find all the files with extension .pc/mk/.h.

```
find $path -type f \( -name "*.pc" -o -name "*.mk" -o -name "*.h" \)
```

But I want to add 1 more check with same command that will exclude file name like abc.pc and xyz.mk from that find command.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove something from a UNIX command, just add a pipe with a `grep -v`:

```
... | grep -v "abc.pc" | grep -v "xyz.mk"
```

Comment: Thank You!! Its ok but issue is that if 2 files like common.pc and common.mk so i used grep -v "common*".there is 1 directory named common(/home/common/codes/*).so no files are  coming.I need to use each full file name 2 times.in example only 2 file but there is lots of file starting with common.